# How to combine GROUP BY, ORDER BY and HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I combine correctly this statement.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*)
FROM user_log
GROUP BY Email
ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Let me know

Comment: General GROUP BY tip: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`ORDER BY` is always last...

However, you need to pick the fields you **ACTUALLY WANT** then select only those and group by them.  `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY Email` will give you **RANDOM VALUES** for all the fields but `Email`.  Most RDBMS will not even allow you to do this because of the issues it creates, but MySQL is the exception.

```
SELECT Email, COUNT(*)
FROM user_log
GROUP BY Email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC
```

Comment: (When you have a `GROUP BY`), the same logic applies for all fields you put in the `SELECT` list, the `HAVING` clause and the `ORDER BY` clause. So, it also applies for `ORDER BY UpdateDate`. Unless `UpdateDate` depends on `Email`, you'll get a rather random ordering.

Answer (score -3):

**Steps for Using Group by,Having By  and Order by...**

```
Select Attitude ,count(*) from Person
group by person
HAving PersonAttitude='cool and friendly'
Order by PersonName.
```

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule is: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function,"

Answer (score -6):

Your code should be contain `WHILE` before `group by` and `having` :

```
SELECT Email, COUNT(*)

FROM user_log

WHILE Email IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY Email

HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC
```

Comment: Nice copy paste :P