# Not getting result using GROUP BY, ORDER BY and HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch records combining `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `HAVING`, but I am not getting result / desirable result. This is my table `test`:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----+---------------------+------+
| id                                   | no  | date_entered        | name |
+--------------------------------------+-----+----------------------------+
| c44d1977-0193-a2f1-00f9-57e4c53ba416 | 104 | 2016-09-23 06:02:16 | Z-44 |
| ca1879a2-df08-4fe3-b144-57e4d2ab0c62 | 104 | 2016-09-23 06:57:35 | Z-44 |
| 5dd46d35-358a-314e-30fa-57e4d2ca92ad | 104 | 2016-09-23 06:59:17 | Z-44 |
| d474cc6a-e7a1-15d1-d209-57e4c5aa607d | 105 | 2016-09-23 05:03:08 | Z-45 |
| db77b687-763d-b63a-be77-57e4d2e246fb | 105 | 2016-09-23 05:51:41 | Z-45 |
| 70f0f514-c0fd-ddfd-55a6-57e4d21b5e3c | 106 | 2016-09-23 05:29:39 | Z-46 |
+--------------------------------------+-----+---------------------+------+
```

And I want result something like this :

```
+--------------------------------------+-----+----------+
| id                                   | no  | COUNT(*) |
+--------------------------------------+-----+----------+
| 5dd46d35-358a-314e-30fa-57e4d2ca92ad | 104 |        3 |
| db77b687-763d-b63a-be77-57e4d2e246fb | 105 |        3 |
+--------------------------------------+-----+----------+
```

Here I want to fetch only those records which are belongs to same `no` and are oldest one. Also this query should run where there are more than one records belongs to same `no`. So this is the query I am using

```
SELECT id, no, COUNT(*) 
FROM test 
GROUP BY no 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY date_entered DESC;
```

But I am getting this result

```
+--------------------------------------+-----+----------+
| id                                   | no  | COUNT(*) |
+--------------------------------------+-----+----------+
| c44d1977-0193-a2f1-00f9-57e4c53ba416 | 104 |        3 |
| d474cc6a-e7a1-15d1-d209-57e4c5aa607d | 105 |        3 |
+--------------------------------------+-----+----------+
```

Now, I have look around for help and I got this [How to combine GROUP BY, ORDER BY and HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734276/how-to-combine-group-by-order-by-and-having) and as mentioned in accepted answer that `However, you need to pick the fields you ACTUALLY WANT then select only those and group by them`, so I tried this query also:

```
SELECT id, no, count(*) 
FROM test 
GROUP BY id, no 
HAVING count(*) > 1 
ORDER BY date_entered DESC;
```

But after executing this query, I got none. Kindly guide me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY date_entered DESC), ',', 1) as id,
       no, COUNT(*) 
FROM test 
GROUP BY no 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ;
```

There are some limitations on this approach.  The default internal size for `GROUP_CONCAT()` is 1,024 bytes.  This is easily reconfigured, but it assumes that you do not have too many ids for a given number.

There are alternative approaches, using variables or more complex SQL statements.  However, this is the simplest for fitting into your current query.

Comment: Thanks @Gorden, it worked. But there will be many ids for given number and as you mentioned, will need to reconfigure internal size for `GROUP_CONCAT()`. May I know, what will be the complications? Also, it would be great help for me, if you explain your query a little bit, mostly `substring_index()/group_concat()`. Thank you.

Comment: `group_concat()`brings all the ids into a long string order by the date.  The `substring_index()` pulls out the first one.

Comment: Hey @GordonLinoff, do you have any idea on how to port this query to SQL SERVER 2008?

Comment: @TonyMontana . . . If you have a new question, then pose it as a question, not in a comment.