# Query failed: syntax error at or near "GROUP"

Tags: sql

What's wrong with this query?

```
SELECT 
    p.product_id,
    SUM(od.quantity)
FROM product AS p
JOIN order_details AS od    
ON p.product_id = od.product_id
HAVING SUM(od.quantity) >= 100
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734276/how-to-combine-group-by-order-by-and-having 

refer this.

Answer (score 2):

Group By should be before Having in the select

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
HAVING condition
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific order of the SQL script, that needs to be followed for execution. Please check the below image, it may help you to revisit the SQL query.

[image]